# Windows server 2003 shared folders

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have a server with OS Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 (x64). There are some shared folders on this server.  Opening a network share by the host name `\\Serv` or IP address `\\192.168.0.111`, there is a difference in symbols case of folders names.

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this oddity with samba hosts on linux as well.  Folders that are set to all caps will show up in all lowercase when browsed via IP address.  This behavior can be modified if you mount/use these folders via the "net use" command and specify the folder name with the case you desire.  They should then appear as they were typed in the "net use" tool.

In any case, CIFS/SMB is not (or should not be) case sensitive so you shouldn't see any problems with this behavior.

If this is causing a problem, please update your post and I'll look into it on my end.